# Cant see sub process output in celery logs

Tags: django, celery

So I a Celery task that creates a sub process. When I run this on the celery command line tool (not the daemonized version) I can see the output, but when I daemonized it, I no longer see the output from my sub process. I have the

```
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="info"
```

setting in my `/etc/default/celeryd` config file (so I'm using celeryd to daemonize it).

Is there someway I can see this output? and if so, perhaps configure each worker to use a seperate log?

thanks.